# specify break points for histogram in Lets Plot Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lets-plot

ggPlot2 allows the break points to be specified for the tabulation of the histogram.  To date, I have not figured out how to do this using Lets Plot Kotlin.  Is there an approach for doing this using geom_histogram() in Lets Plot for Kotlin?

I guess that I could try to use geom_bar() directly and build up a histogram from base elements, but it seems like if ggPlot2 allows this, why not Lets Plot for Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust number/location of bins using [geomHistogram()](https://lets-plot.org/kotlin/-lets--plot--kotlin/org.jetbrains.letsPlot.geom/geom-histogram/index.html) parameters `bins`, `binWidth`, `center` and `boundary` if that is what you wanted.

To customize breaks along the x-axis you can try `breaks` and `labels` parameters in `scaleXContinuous()`.

Comment: scaleXContinuous() controls the axis. It does not control the tabulation of the data.  bins and binWidth force you to all lets-plot to tabulate the counts. You are at the mercy of how it tabulates the data. I ended up using geom_rect() to build the plot up.

Comment: @ManuelRossetti glad you were able to find a workaround. However it would be great to know which exactly histogram-related features of ggplot2 are missing in lets-plot.